# BackstopJS testing for the entire application pages

Tags: testing

How to test all the pages in backstop JS. I am only able to test one page. Because I am giving just one url and referenceURL. How can we make it test all the pages in the application. Only one screenshot is provided. Need to find all the screenshot and changes in the apllication.

Answer (score 0):

You can have different scenarios for each page and run the tests. Or you can have two files to keep it generic and reusable and in one file just declare all the pages and device details like below

**basicConfig.js**

```
const projectId = "test"; // 

let baseUrl = "YourURL"; // 


// Replace the values of the below array with the relative URLs of your website. E.g., "/about", "/contact", "/pricing", etc.
// Use just "/" to test the homepage of your website.
// Add as many relative URLs as you need.
const relativeUrls =[
  "/about",
  "/documentation",
  "/case-studies/",
  "/solutions/",
  "/blog/"
];


// Leave the below array as is if you want to test your website using the viewports listed below.
// The suported viewports are: phone (320px X 480px), tablet (1024px X 768px), and desktop (1280px X 1024px).
// No other viewports are supported.
// You can remove the viewports that you don't need, but at least one of them is required.
const viewports = [
  "phone",
  "tablet",
  "desktop",
];

module.exports = {
  baseUrl,
  projectId,
  relativeUrls,
  viewports
};
```

In other file, keep the scenario config.

**mainConfig.js**

```
const THREE_SECONDS_IN_MS = 3000;
const scenarios = [];
const viewports = [];

basicConfig.relativeUrls.map(relativeUrl => {
  scenarios.push({
    label: relativeUrl,
    url: `${basicConfig.baseUrl}${relativeUrl}`,
    requireSameDimensions: false
  });
});

basicConfig.viewports.map(viewport => {
  if (viewport === "phone") {
    pushViewport(viewport, 320, 480);
  }
  if (viewport === "tablet") {
    pushViewport(viewport, 1024, 768);
  }
  if (viewport === "desktop") {
    pushViewport(viewport, 1280, 1024);
  }
});

function pushViewport(viewport, width, height) {
  viewports.push({
    name: viewport,
    width,
    height,
  });
}

module.exports = {
  id: basicConfig.projectId,
  viewports,
  scenarios,
  paths: {
    bitmaps_reference: "test/backstop_data/bitmaps_reference",
    bitmaps_test: "test/backstop_data/bitmaps_test",
    html_report: "test/backstop_data/html_report"
  },
  report: ["CI"],
  engine: "puppeteer",
  engineOptions: {
    args: ["--no-sandbox"]
  },
  asyncCaptureLimit: 5,
  asyncCompareLimit: 50,
};
```

Hope it helps you, let me know if you need any other help.

Thanks!